# Как перевести Google Tables в json?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток!
Возник такой вопрос как же перевести данные с гугл таблицы в json формат c помощью языка python? Так сказать парсинг гугл таблиц на питоне. И есть ли какие-то может заготовки?

Comment: Предоставьте для примера Google таблицу и желаемый результат.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11WR6rwQhL4wUDN8I77ju_5rzZl8IglsUjtUDI6pZsAQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: Смотрите я хочу чтобы данные с таблицы хранились в моем json файле. Это возможно?

Comment: Обратите внимание в сторону Google API

Comment: [Пример использования Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)